# In Excel, how to return the month for the LA value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to get the returned value of `Nov-18`.
How is that possible?
Please take a look at the Excel snippet example:

[image: Snippet]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: would the value be unique?  If not, how do you want to deal with duplicates?

Comment: Assuming the value is in `H2`, you can use `=H2`. I do suspect you want something else, but you will have to explain what you need and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Also please show the column and row headers in the picture so we can actually create a formula that would work for your data.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yeah that would kind of defeat the purpose of doing anything if you had to manually input the range reference everytime. I know the question is very broadly formulated and honestly, kind of deserves an answer like that, but it still gave me a good chuckle

Comment: Yes it would be unique but it could change within the matrix in an orderly form

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That would return `Nov-18` not `Nov/18`.  Maybe `=TEXT(H2,"mmm/yy")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes the purpose is to return the month (i.e. Nov-18). I corrected the date on the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE in and INDEX formula:

```
=INDEX(6:6,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(G7:M10)/(G7:M10 = F14),1))
```

Comment: I just changed the snippet. Could you reformulate? Thanks!

Comment: @Russmanov, you could do a little bit of effort... all your doing is requesting code. Your lucky Scott gave you something, you just need to edit the columns to your needs..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Looking at your data assuming you have data in F6:M10. you can use below formula in cell against your input cell where you are giving LA i.e. G12 is your input cell and H12 is for formula : =INDEX(G6:L6,1,MAX(IF(G7:L10=G12,ROW(G7:L10),0))-5) then press Ctrl+shft+Enter..it will work.Now keep changing input in G12 and you will get output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below array formula in cell F7 :
=INDEX(A1:H1,1,MAX(IF(B2:H5=E7,COLUMN(B1:H5),0)))

Considering Your data is available in cells A1:H5 and your input(i.e. LA) in cell E7.

Do not forget to press CTRL+SHFT+ENter after writing the formula

If you want to riturn the house name as well type formula in cell F8:

=INDEX(A1:A5,MAX(IF(B2:G5=E7,ROW(B2:H5),0)),1)